# UL LI 4 Column List: Center in each column

Tags: css, list, navigation

I'm building a footer navigation with four columns:

```
<ul>
    <li>Top Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>sub 1a</li>
            <li>sub 1b</li>
            <li>sub 1c</li>
            <li>sub 1d</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Top Level 2
        <ul>
            <li>sub 2a</li>
            <li>sub 2b</li>
            <li>sub 2c</li>
            <li>sub 2d</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    .... (repreat 2 more times)....
</ul>
```

I have each of the 4 columns (li's) set at a width of 25%, which renders the list as follows (where the pipes represent the columns, but are not visible...)

```
| Top Level 1        | Top Level 2        | Top Level 3        | Top Level 4
| sub 1a             | sub 2a             | sub 3a             | sub 4a
| sub 1b             | sub 2b             | sub 3b             | sub 4b
| sub 1c             | sub 2c             | sub 3c             | sub 4c
| sub 1d             | sub 2d             | sub 3d             | sub 4d
```

What I want to do, but can't seem to figure out, is this:

```
|     Top Level 1    |     Top Level 2    |     Top Level 3    |     Top Level 4
|     sub 1a         |     sub 2a         |     sub 3a         |     sub 4a
|     sub 1b         |     sub 2b         |     sub 3b         |     sub 4b
|     sub 1c         |     sub 2c         |     sub 3c         |     sub 4c
|     sub 1d         |     sub 2d         |     sub 3d         |     sub 4d
```

So the columns stay the same, but each list inside the column is more at the center of the column, but not aligned centered.

Also, I want to do it so that the page is fluid and responsive. I don't want to hard-code a set pixel amount. For example, I don't want margin-left:50px; on all the elements.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/eNEjLp

```
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul.wrapper{
  display:flex;
}

ul.wrapper>li{
          flex:1;
  padding-left:4%;
  border-left:2px dashed #333;
}

ul.wrapper>li ul li{
  padding-left:0%;
}
```

And play with `padding-left` in percentaje for example

I remove it the prefix, but the example is with prefix